# не прогружается страница на WP после добавления php

Tags: php, wordpress

В проекте присутствует работа с сессиями в хедере всем страницам добавляется session_start();
проблема заключается в том что когда я добавил на страницу код приведенный ниже она перестала загружаться а при попытке сохранить WP выдает ошибку 500

```
 echo '
     <div class="csrc_info">
    <h4>Shipping address</h4>
    <p><span>$_SESSION['customer_first_name']</span> <span>$_SESSION['customer_last_name']</span></p>
    <p>$_SESSION['customer_address']</p>
    <p>$_SESSION['customer_suite']</p>
    <p><span>$_SESSION['customer_city']</span>, <span>$_SESSION['customer_province']</span>, <span>$_SESSION['customer_postalcode']</span></p>
    <p>$_SESSION['customer_country']</p>
    <p>$_SESSION['customer_phone']</p>
    </div>
    <p><a href="checkout-first" class="csrc_edit">Edit</a></p>

    ';
```

Comment: Не понял - вы хотите сохранить php код в админке, в редакторе страницы???

Comment: нет, через сниппеты

Comment: Какие  сниппеты, какими плагинами подключены, ничего не понятно. У вас там 202 причины ошибок. Создайте минимальный, самодостаточный, воспроизводимый пример (см. правила сообщества)

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '
<div class="csrc_info">
<h4>Shipping address</h4>
<p><span>'.$_SESSION['customer_first_name'.'</span> <span>'.$_SESSION['customer_last_name'.'</span></p>
<p>'.$_SESSION['customer_address'.'</p>
<p>'.$_SESSION['customer_suite'.'</p>
<p><span>'.$_SESSION['customer_city'.'</span>, <span>'.$_SESSION['customer_province'.'</span>, <span>'.$_SESSION['customer_postalcode'.'</span></p>
<p>'.$_SESSION['customer_country'.'</p>
<p>'.$_SESSION['customer_phone'.'</p>
</div>
<p><a href="checkout-first" class="csrc_edit">Edit</a></p>    ';
```

На будущее - погуглите как вставлять переменные в `echo`, и вообще в строки